# Phrase / term for a workplace with flexible hours?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I had come across a phrase (I can no longer recall) that means that a workplace ABC has no fixed work hours and the deliverable work can be done as and when an employee pleases; just that it should be done in time.

> ABC Company practices X work culture.

Where X sounded like a somewhat corporate term.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't simply _flexible working_?

Comment: Hot desking perhaps...

Answer (score 2):

I found **flexitime** or **flextime** (an alternative spelling).

In [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flexitime#English), it is defined as:

> An arrangement that allows employees to set their own working hours within agreed limits; normally must include certain periods (core time) when they must be at work.